# ios: Is it possible to find the other device ‘s location with specific IMEI, RSSI or phone number from the app side?

Tags: ios, core-location

I am using one iphone and one other device in my application, both of them have sim card inside.

What I want to do is to trace the location of device from the iphone side. I can get iphone’s location by CoreLocation framework and it works very well. But how can I get the location of device?

Does CoreLocation or other framework provide API function for us to get the location with the argument of specific CellID, IMEI, RSSI or phone number?

Answer (score 1):

To make it short: **No**.
The geolocation service you want to access is called network triangulation and is handled service-provider side. Your app won't get those data from any framework.

**EDIT:** iOS do use network triangulation and wifi positioning, but you won't have access to that info. All you will get is the processed data from iOS, without being able to know how it found it.

Comment: As I know, iphone can use GPS, Cell Tower or Wifi to find the location via CoreLocation framework (although we have no control over how the location is determined...). Does not cell tower method use network triangulation to find the location?

Comment: It does, but you don't have access to that info, only to the result of all this data, processed by iOS.

Comment: You are welcome ! I edited my answer to include my comment. If it helped, please consider to accept the answer :)